# retrieve value from sql server and passing it to string to write it into txt file using VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I am retrieving some data from sql server and trying to write it to a text file, I am getting error in retrieving and passing it to variable Could you please help me in this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please edit your answer and add the code you are using, otherwise there's no way anyone can help. Make sure that it is a [mcve], and to follow the suggestions on the [Ask] page. I also recommend taking a [tour] of the site. All of this will make your question a better one, and increase your chances to get good answers. Thank you!

Comment: Please find the code snippet below:

Comment: @AgasthiSubramani press the [edit] and add your code to the question, not in comments

Comment: "WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN concat(' ',B.COLTYPE, ' (', B.LENGTH, ' )') " & _
"WHEN 'LONGVAR' THEN concat(' ',B.COLTYPE, ' (', B.LENGTH, ' )') " & _
"WHEN 'DECIMAL' THEN concat(' ',B.COLTYPE, ' (', B.LENGTH, ' )') " & _
"WHEN 'BINARY' THEN concat(' ',B.COLTYPE, ' (', B.LENGTH, ' )') " & _
"ELSE concAT(' ', B.COLTYPE) " & _

Comment: END as str2 , " & _
"CASE b.NULLS2 " & _
"WHEN 'N' THEN ' NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,' " & _
   "     Else ' , ' " & _
"END as str3 " & _

Comment: "FROM DBO.SYSTABLES as A , DBO.SYSCOL as B " & _
"WHERE A.TYPE = '" + TextBox3.Text + "' AND A.NAME = '" + TextBox2.Text + "' AND " & _
"A.CREATOR = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND A.CREATOR =  B.TBCREATOR AND A.NAME = B.TBNAME " & _
"ORDER BY B.COLNO ")

Comment: Dim dt = SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
            objWriter.Write(dt)
            objWriter.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Text written to file")

Comment: End If


    End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of detail regarding the error. Assuming your query is working and returning data to the table, Streamwriter.Write(dt) won't return the data in the table, it will return the name of the table or something like that.  to get all the data you need to either loop through the rows and columns and print each one as you like or use dt.WriteXML(myIOStream), obWRiter.(myIOstream).  You can also try streamwriter.write(dt.writexml()).  I haven't tried anything out so you'll need to work on the code.